# distinguish shared objects from position independent executables

Tags: elf

I'm looking for a fast way to check if a ELF binary is a shared object or a position independent executable. I think a can do that by checking the contained symbols / functions. I'm looking for a more efficient way of not having to read the complete file. I have to perform the check on different platforms, at least Android, Linux (32 and 64 bit).

Comment: On Solaris and old versions of Android there exists a `DF_1_PIE` flag (a bit of the `DT_FLAGS_1`) that is supposed to tell you exactly this. The story of this field on Linux is really amusing. Quoting from a paper by Denis Silakov: "dynamic entry DT_FLAGS_1 was first added in the LSB 1.0, withdrawn in the LSB 1.2, added once again in the LSB 1.3 and finally dropped in the LSB 2.0."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm looking for a fast way to check if a ELF binary is a shared object or a position independend executable.

There is *no way* to check: a PIE executable *is* a shared object.

> I think a can do that by checking the contained symbols / functions.

Symbols can be stripped, and once they are, you *can't* tell.

> shared objects and executables they normally differ by the linked startup code

That's true: the PIE is normally linked with `Scrt1.o`, but a shared library is normally not. But there is nothing to prevent a shared library to be linked with `Scrt1.o` as well, and in a stripped binary even finding that startup code may be somewhat problematic.

If what you really want is to distinguish between a shared library and a PIE executable which you built *yourself* (rather than solving a general case of *any* shared library and *any* PIE), then checking for presence of `PT_INTERP` (`readelf -l a.out | grep INTERP`) is likely the easiest way to go: a PIE executable is guaranteed to have `PT_INTERP`, and shared libraries normally don't have it (`libc.so.6` is a notable exception).

Comment: When Creating shared objects and executables they normally differ by the linked startup code. Is there really no difference between PIEs and shared objects?

Comment: For more about what `PT_INTERP` does see http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~dww4s/articles/ld_linux.html

Comment: By the way, you can run `libc.so.6` as a program (and it prints some info); its `.interp` section is not some kind of fake/artifact.

Comment: N.B.: this is how [IDA 6.7 does it too](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/6.7/): "ELF: if a dynamic shared object file has ".interp" section, do not mark it as DLL (it's a position-independent executable)".

Answer (score 0):

Try the [elfutils](https://fedorahosted.org/elfutils/) and the included program *eh-readelf*:

```
eh-readelf --file-header $ELFFILE
```

showw you the file header and what kind of file it is:

```
...
Typ:                               EXEC (Executable file)
...
```

or

```
Typ:                               DYN (Shared object file)
```

In combination with a little `sed` line you should get the results you want.

Comment: seems that does not work for PIEs (executables build with g++ and flags -fPIC -pie). The type for the executable is also DYN.