# Determining whether an elf file is executable or a library

Tags: linux, elf

I have the following problem: I have an elf file and I want to know whether that elf file can be run as a standalone executable or not. So for shared libraries e.g., `.so` files, I want to have `False` as a result and for ready-to-run binaries I want `True` as an output. I tried to leverage `file`  to achieve this, but apparently the information given is not enough. Consider

`file /usr/bin/sudo
/usr/bin/sudo: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3e4fbfd5a73126630bcc22d5dee68c32e2813566, stripped`

where I actually expected the output to be `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`, like for the `gcc` compiler:

`file /usr/bin/gcc-5
/usr/bin/gcc-5: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=b3417f0bc306e9b0afe35e778b5e4702f2d22b26, stripped`

What am I missing here and are there any other ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: *"What am I missing here..."* - As I understand it, ELF executables re-use *"dynamically linked"* to mean ASLR (i.e., a program compiler with `-fPIC` or `-fPIE`). Also see [Readelf reports program is a shared library instead of executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30555248/608639).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to have False as a result and for ready-to-run binaries I want True as an output.

In general, your goal is unachievable: it is possible to build a library that is ready to run (e.g. `/lib64/libc.so.6` on Linux) and also to build an executable that will crash on startup despite reporting `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`.

It is also *ill*-advised to try to run any binary unless you know where that binary came from and what its intended result of execution is.

> What am I missing here

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522357/50617) explains, many recent Linux distributions build PIE executables by default.

> are there any other ways to achieve my goal?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351525/50617).